# Automatically read the spring.config.additional-location value in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, config

I got spring boot app and I am building this app and then creating the jar file out of it.

and then I am executing my jar file with below command

**java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar rdk-factory-data-deploy-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8080 --ajp.port=0 --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:OraDoc --spring.datasource.username=system --spring.datasource.password=MyPasswd123 --spring.config.additional-location=file:/Users/bharatsuthar/HGW/codebaseDevelopmentRepo1/factory-data-generation-tool/rdk-factory-data-config/ --logging.config=file:/Users/bharatsuthar/HGW/codebaseDevelopmentRepo1/factory-data-generation-tool/rdk-factory-data-config/logback-spring.xml --certFilePath=/Users/bharatsuthar/HGW/codebaseDevelopmentRepo1/factory-data-generation-tool/rdk-factory-data-config/prodcert/**

my goal is to read the **spring.config.additional-location** value in my java code but I am unable to read this value.

I have tried with below code but my code is not working and I am not able to read this path.

```
System.getProperty("spring.config.additional-location")
```

I think above way is not right way to read..though I can read the value but I want to read this automatically in spring boot app.

Can someone please help on me on this how can I read **spring.config.additional-location** this ?

How can I derive this path **spring.config.additional-location** without using **System.getProperty()** ?

thank you so much

Comment: It isn't a system variable so trying to read it will obviously fail. Use the `Environment` to get the property instead. But why do you need this property in the first place? It is something to be used by Spring Boot.

Comment: I am placing some text file to be read under this location and I am reading that text file in my spring boot app .